# How to merge several Facebook pages of the same celebrity in to two main ones

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

We have recently undertaken work for a celebrity who has several pages under his name, they are all owned by him and he has given us administrator rights to all of them.

In order to make all those pages manageable and to be able to have a clear touch point with the existing and future fans, I would like to merge those pages into two main ones.

I have tried to do that through the official process but although the names and content are similar it doesn't seem to be possible.

What is the correct way to achieve this?
Is there an email where I could contact support and explain what I want to do and provide them with all the official documents supporting my case?

Comment: What is the error you getting when merging?